# How do I set SVG user units when the height/width values are React props?

Tags: reactjs, svg

Newbie here, and this is my first stackoverflow question, so apologies if this a poorly formed question.

I'm working in React and generating an SVG with user defined inputs. I'm trying to define user units as mm instead of the default px, but I can't seem to find the right syntax for using props as the height/width values AND setting the units at the same time. I currently have the width/height values set by props, and I can successfully define units if I give a fixed value (15mm, for example), but I'm not able to do both at the same time.

```
// app.js

...

state = {
   svgWidth: 200,
   svgHeight: 200,
};

handleChange = (e) => {
   const name = e.target.id;
   const value = parseFloat(e.target.value
   this.setState({ [name]: value });
};

...

<Inputs
   {...this.state}
   handleChange={this.handleChange}
/>

<SVG
  {...this.state}
/>

//inputs.js

...

<TextField
   id="svgWidth"
   value={props.svgWidth}
   onChange={handleChange}
/>

<TextField
   id="svgHeight"
   value={props.svgHeight}
   onChange={handleChange}
/>


// svg.js

...

<svg width={props.svgWidth} height={props.svgHeight}>
   ...
</svg>
```

Comment: have you [looked at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35360547/2733506)? also some more [good reading](https://mpetroff.net/2013/08/analysis-of-svg-units/) :)

Comment: Those links do not address my original question, but the second one did answer the issue that came up once I answered the original question. Thank you for that help, I really appreciate it. I'm editing my original question to reflect the solution.

Comment: you can write an answer to your question, I'll upvote it for u :)

Comment: Thanks! I did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected, my original question was just a lack of experience with the syntax. I was able to define units alongside props as the value by using template literals to concatenate the variable and the unit indicator.

```
// svg.js

...

<svg 
   width={`${props.svgWidth}mm`}
   height={`${props.svgHeight}mm`}
>
   ...
</svg>
```

However, in order link the svg user units to the "real world" units defined at the top level svg element, I had to define the svg viewBox to be the same dimensions.

```
// svg.js

...

<svg
   width={`${props.svgWidth}mm`}
   height={`${props.svgHeight}mm`}
   viewBox={`0 0 ${props.svgWidth} ${props.svgHeight}`}
>
   ...
</svg>
```

Thanks for the assist, John.

Comment: Sorry, totally didn't follow that this is what you were trying to do in the question! This is a good way to add `mm` to your size. Assuming `svgWidth` is already in `mm` units! :)